# Two warnings when compiling my java applet

Tags: java, applet, appletviewer

```
package homework1;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Homework1A extends Applet {

    public  void paint( Graphics g ){
        g.drawString("CIS 35A Student Learning Outcomes ",40,60);
    }
}
```

This is the warning that I get

```
The serializable class Homework1A does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long 
Homework1A.java    /homework1/src/homework1    line 5    Java Problem
```

also there was another warning  like this

```
Warning: Can't read AppletViewer properties file:
```

but it disappeared after I run my code a few times.

Comment: How are you compiling and running your code?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?  As an aside.  Unless specified.  1) Code frames rather than applets.  2) Use Swing rather than AWT.  If specified, slap the person who decided that and tell them that they should not be teaching applets, should not be teaching AWT, and should not be teaching, period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a serial version UID such as: `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;` in your class.

You can use this as reference: [Serial IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it)